# nautilus crash when try to give permission on folder 14.04

Tags: active-directory

Nautilus crash problem when i trying to open folder properties and go to permission option at that time nautilus crash. I am not able to set permission on it.

Comment: Have the same issue buddy! But as far as I remember only when I access my admin user's files from root.